# Can you discover who I am?

Tags: riddle, cipher

I made my first puzzle for PSE!

The string below is an encryption for the enigma to be solved. In order to find the answer you must:

- Discover what the dots and zeros translate to;
- Find the answer to whatever the decrypted text is!

**The string:**
00000000000000000000.00000000000000000000000.000000000000000. 0000000000000.000000000.00000000000000.000000000000000000000.00000000000000000000.00000.0000000000000000000. 00000000000000000000.000000000000000. 00000000000000000000.00000000.00000. 00000.00000000000000.0000., 0000000000000000000.0.000000000.0000. 00000000000000000000.00000000.00000. 00000000000000000000.000000000000000000.000000000000000.0000000000000000.0000000000000000.00000.000000000000000000.. 000000000.00000000000000. 00000000000000000000.00000000.00000. 0000.0.000000000000000000.00000000000., 0000000000000000000000000.000000000000000.000000000000000000000. 00000000000000000000000.000000000.000000000000.000000000000. 00000000.00000.0.000000000000000000. 0000000000000.00000. 0000000000000000000.000000000.00000000000000.0000000.. 00000000000000000000000.00000000.000000000000000. 0.0000000000000. 000000000.?

Good luck!

Tip:

> It's a band!

Comment: Hi MrNoob and welcome to Puzzling :) Is this a puzzle you created yourself or did you find it elsewhere? If from elsewhere, please could you mention where it comes from in the question text, as our site policy says we need to make sure the original content creator is credited. Thanks, and Happy Puzzling!

Comment: FAO anyone reading - the OP replied to my comment above to say "Thanks @Stiv! Yes, I was the one who created it. I haven't seen anything similar to this, although, if you have, please contact me in order for me to remove the puzzle." It's an original puzzle.

Answer (score 3):

The way to interpret this cipher is to:

> Count the number of 0-characters between each dot - this then translates via A1Z26 to a letter of the alphabet.
>
>  Each run of zeros thus encodes a single letter. Words are differentiated by spaces after a dot, and a dot or comma immediately following a dot is a punctuation mark included in the message.

The message thus decodes to:

> TWO MINUTES TO THE END, SAID THE TROPPER. IN THE DARK, YOU WILL HEAR ME SING. WHO AM I?
>
>  It seems we now have a riddle to answer!

What do we make of this, then? Well, note that these words are:

> a mash-up of several different song titles by the metal band, **Iron Maiden**:
>
>  [**2 Minutes to** Midnight](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9qbRHY1l0vc)
>  [Childhood's **End**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EuHAE5TvW0E)
>  [**The Trooper**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X4bgXH3sJ2Q) (I suspect 'TROPPER' is just a typo in the puzzle...)
>  [Fear of **the Dark**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J0N1yY937qg)

As a result of this, I suspect the answer to this puzzle is:

> **IRON MAIDEN**, or the band's lead singer, **BRUCE DICKINSON**, who would have been the person to sing these words...